# Call function in anonymus block

Tags: sql, plsql

```
DECLARE
  vv_1 emp.id%TYPE;
  CURSOR cursor_name IS 
    SELECT id, function_name(vv_1) 
      FROM emp;
  cursor_name1 cursor_name%rowtype;
BEGIN
  FOR cursor_name1 IN cursor_name
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(function(vv_1));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

My function `function_name` is computing some kind of tax for salary.
In this anonymous block I need to call the function and to calculate with it the salary for **all** employers.

`function_name()` is set to run using the `id` of employer as a parameter.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first issue is that you are not telling us what problem exactly you have. If that is a compilation error you are not showing us what is the compiler error message.

Comment: There is not any error, just don't display me what I need. My function calculate the sallary without taxes for a single employer. I need to introduce that function to this anonymus block and to apply it to all employers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't assigned any value to the vv_1 variable you're using as a parameter. You need to assign the right value to the vv_1 variable before calling the function:

```
DECLARE
  vv_1 emp.id%TYPE;
  CURSOR cursor_name IS 
    SELECT id, function_name(vv_1)
    FROM emp;
  cursor_name1 cursor_name%rowtype;
BEGIN
  FOR cursor_name1 IN cursor_name
  LOOP
    vv_1 := cursor_name1.id;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(function_name(vv_1));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

As you're already calling the function in the cursor, you wouldn't have to call it again -you'll need to pass the right parameter too (i.e.: use the id field):

```
DECLARE
  vv_1 emp.id%TYPE;
  CURSOR cursor_name IS 
    SELECT id, function_name(id) function_value
    FROM emp;
BEGIN
  FOR cursor_name1 IN cursor_name
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cursor_name1.function_value);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The logic seems to be right, but I get an error there: PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'cursor_name1' reference is out of scope. Do you have any ideea why?

Comment: corrected - declaration is not required when a FOR loop is used

Comment: Shouldn't `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(function_value);` be `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vv_1);`?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger - If you're referring to the second code example above I think that it should be `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cursor_name1.function_value);` or `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(function_name(cursor_name1.id));`. In the first example it looks to me like it should be `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(function_name(vv_1));`.

Comment: You were right! I've just edited my answer! Sorry about that!!

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL Statement (cursor), you select `function_name(vv_1)`. You should give it an alias so that it is easier to refer to the computed value when you iterate over the cursor. I chose `func_value` but it's up to you what best describes its function:

```
CURSOR cursor_name IS 
  SELECT id, 
         function_name(vv_1) func_value
    FROM emp;
```

Then, in the iteration, you can refer to it using `cursor_name1.func_value`:

```
FOR cursor_name1 IN cursor_name
LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cursor_name1.func_value);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be made simpler by using a SQL-statement `FOR` loop:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT function_name(id) AS FUNCTION_VALUE FROM emp) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aRow.FUNCTION_VALUE);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Done this way the need for the DECLARE block goes away as there's no need to declare any variables.

If there's a preference for invoking the function from inside the loop, which you might need to do if, for example, `function_name` is a packaged function which is not publicly exposed by the package spec, you could rewrite this as

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT ID FROM emp) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(function_name(aRow.ID));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This can be made simpler by using a SQL-statement `FOR` loop:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT function_name(id) AS FUNCTION_VALUE FROM emp) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aRow.FUNCTION_VALUE);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Done this way the need for the DECLARE block goes away as there's no need to declare any variables.

If there's a preference for invoking the function from inside the loop, which you might be necessary if `function_name` is a packaged function which is not publicly exposed by the package spec, you could rewrite this as

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT ID FROM emp) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(function_name(aRow.ID));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.